# I want to apply select2 js with activeadmin using activeadmin_addons gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, jquery-select2

```
I want to apply select2 js with activeadmin using activeadmin_addons gem on has_may through associations but when I apply all the things which are mentioned in gem it looks like select2 js not loading

I have apply all the changes for like what we need to include in js and css files 

when I try to add new record by add more record it gives error like this
 **$(...).select2 is not a function**
```

Active Admin Form:
**

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs 'Collection details' do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end
    #f.input :wires, :input_html => { :class => "chosen-input" } # other model with has_many relation ship
    f.inputs 'Wires' do
      f.has_many :collection_wires, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true, heading: false do |collection_wire_f|
        collection_wire_f.input :wire
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

**

active_admin.js.coffee

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require activeadmin_addons/all
```

And when I look at page source it shows the select2 loaded before the code uses it and after jquery and jquery ujs

I want wires should be use select2 js to search data when we are on new or edit page.

Please suggest any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution there are issue with path of the js which is not working on development mode when I precompile assets on development mode it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was fixed here: https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/issues/65
and included in [this release](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/releases/tag/v0.9.2)